# What are the equivalent data objects in Bash in comparison to R?

Tags: bash, variable, r

R was the first programming language I learned. It is always a pleasure to learn a new language associated with the first language.

**Here comes my question. What are the equivalent data objects in Bash for the following data objects in R**

I have also given a short description of each data-objects

**Vector** -> single dimension | can take both characters, integer and other standard datatypes (logical, double, complex) | but only one data-type at a  time

**Dataframe** --> two-dimension | collection of vectors of equal length | can take both characters, integer and other standard datatypes | but only one data type in a vector

**List** --> collection of different data types which can even contain functions !!! | a list can contain many lists | list can contain mix up of datatypes.

**Matrix** --> data arranged in two-dimensional rectangular layout | main in elements of same types

**Array** --> multi-dimension storage | standard datatypes

Comment: It has arrays, similar to vector. All data is string. Most of the rest is missing, a shell is not meant for the same type of thing as R. And R is not meant for the same type of thing as a shell.

Comment: Hi. @ctrl-alt-delor can you please write an answer. We all will get benefited.